# PyInstaller file producing error after sent

Tags: python, selenium, debugging, exe, pyinstaller

I have created a PyInstaller file that runs perfectly on my computer. This file contains version 3.7.7 of python, selenium module, requests module, random module, and time module. However, when I attempt to send it to another computer that has the same OS. it produces this error:

```
[1174] Error loading Python lib '/var/folders/lc/sp95n3k172l7wnj34b9fqg9m0000gn/T/_MEINZTtRX/Python': dlopen: dlopen(/var/folders/lc/sp95n3k172l7wnj34b9fqg9m0000gn/T/_MEINZTtRX/Python, 10): Symbol not found: _futimens
  Referenced from: /var/folders/lc/sp95n3k172l7wnj34b9fqg9m0000gn/T/_MEINZTtRX/Python
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
 in /var/folders/lc/sp95n3k172l7wnj34b9fqg9m0000gn/T/_MEINZTtRX/Python
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]
```

It appears that the error is happening because it cannot find a python file. My goal is to run this on a computer with the same OS without python installed. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a software that converts the whole project into an .exe file that can run on any Windows machine.

[Download NSIS](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Download)

There's tonnes of tutorials on how you can proceed from here, I can't explain the whole thing.

Hope this is what you're looking for.